# Nginx map directive only matching default

Tags: nginx, http-headers, multiple-instances

I'm using Nginx's map directive to route users to either stable or beta servers depending on the value of a custom http header. However, Nginx will only match to the default value, even when I've confirmed that the header is 'TEST'.

```
worker_processes  2;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$http_x_cp_client_class" $upstream';

access_log  logs/access.log  main;

upstream dataserver_stable {
    server localhost:8081;
}

upstream dataserver_beta {
    server localhost:8082 fail_timeout=1m;
}

map $http_x-cp-client-class $upstream {
    TEST "dataserver_beta";
    # STABLE "dataserver_stable"; technically redundant I think
    default "dataserver_stable";
}

server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            add_header My-Upstream $upstream;

            proxy_pass       http://$upstream;
            proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
            proxy_read_timeout 10s;
    }
}
}
```

Headers:

Req:

```
GET /pages/widgets/calendar/tradeDateCalendar.tpl.html HTTP/1.1
Host: ny7wlpmurray:81
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
X-CP-Client-Class: TEST
Referer: http://ny7wlpmurray:81/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1629631386.1511812518; _gid=GA1.1.892280347.1511812518
```

Res:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Wed, 29 Nov 2017 21:33:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 594
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"594-1511969617175"
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Nov 2017 15:33:37 GMT
My-Upstream: dataserver_stable
```

Have I written something wrong? I've tried TEST, ~TEST, "TEST", and "~TEST", none of which worked.

Comment: Show request headers and full config

Comment: Did you try putting TEST before default? 
"default value" sets the resulting value if the source value matches none of the specified variants.

Comment: I moved TEST above the default, no change there. Will update the post with  the full config and my req/res headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When converting HTTP request headers to variable names, nginx will [convert hyphens to underscores](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_). Thus, a variable representing the `X-CP-Client-Class` header will be `$http_x_cp_client_class`.

This suggests that your `map` should be declared as follows:

```
map $http_x_cp_client_class $upstream {
```

Comment: Yep, this was it. I was even correctly referencing the variable in my log format directive and didn't notice they were different. Thanks!